# Using Formidable in a Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, formidable

I have a [SendGrid 'Inbound Parse Webhook'](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Inbound_Parse_Webhook/setting_up_the_inbound_parse_webhook.html) posting parsed emails to a Firebase Function. This sends incoming emails in a `multipart/form-data` request to my Firebase function.

I'm trying to use [Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) to parse those requests, but keep getting an error:

> Request aborted at IncomingMessage.< anonymous >

This [has been reported here](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/issues/285) and the solution seems to be to turn off the body parsing, but is that possible in a firebase function?